# Mouse macro recorder loop function

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, macros, automation

I am currently using [Mouse recorder premium](http://www.mouserecorder.com/) (mouse macro recorder).

I have a list of keywords in an excel file, and the task involves manually populating the next numerical column from a webstite.

Procedure:

1. Start with Cell A1.
2. copy content of cell A1 into website search.
3. copy the numerical value that is returned (in a consistent location) to cell B1.
4. Loop and repeat for the entire list (10,000 odd).

I have successfully written a macro in Mouse macro recorder to do steps 1-3. I cannot however figure out a way to loop that macro, so that in the next iteration it starts with the next cell, A2.

Does anyone know any trick to get this to work?

Alternatively if someone knows a s

Comment: I don't know that tool, but what about - instead of using mouse - using keyboard within Excel, so instead of "click B1, insert, click A2, copy" do "activate excel, press right (move A1 -> B1), CTRL-V, press left and down (B1 -> A2), CTRL-C) continue with mouse selecting the right field in the browser" ...

Comment: Auto-IT recorder then edit the script to whatever you like, easy and has extensive support, and it is free and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of step 3 – when you have entered the copied value into B1 – press the down arrow on the vertical scroll once.
[image]

This will step exactly one cell down in the sheet, so where A1 once was, A2 is now present.
In that way, the cell that is to be copied from and pasted to, are always set in the right position before next loop starts.